# How to inherit from DialogTestBase for uni testing RootDialog?

Tags: unit-testing, dialog, botframework

I know it might be stupid to ask, but I can't find how to inherit from DialogTestBase in my test class for the RootDialog. 
I tried to look for the namespace Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Tests, but I couldn't find how to get access to it.
My project can consume only nuget packages, but I couldn't find it in any package in there browser, and the only package which seems to have it is U4.Bot.Builder.TestBase which was uninstalled by its owners (https://www.nuget.org/packages/U4.Bot.Builder.TestBase/2.0.35).

Any idea?

Comment: the class can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/3c912ec90ad08a63e7ffd2256998db3521b028aa/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Tests/DialogTestBase.cs)  are you not able to download the source code and add the project to your code?  Or simply copying and pasting the classes you need into your project?

Comment: If I'll try to copy DialogTestBase to my project, I'll need to copy more classes which it depends on. In the link you gave me it looks like its written under the Bot.Builder package. In addition I saw in some other question here in stackoverflow that it is recommended to inherit from DialogTestBase when writin uni-testing to dialogs, So I assumed I can import the namespace it lives in (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Test) - but I didn't succeeded doing that.